# ! Package PGF Math Error: Array index out of bounds

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, errors

I am trying to creates sets of commands to automatically draw some functions which have complicated mathematical relations. However, I face this error when I run the function. I faced this after I added triangular functions to my commands. How may I debug this error?

```
%pdfLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
    \def\dh{{#1}[0]}
    \def\db{{#1}[1]}
    \def\dt{{#1}[2]}
    \def\dr{{#1}[3]}
    \def\dd{{#1}[4]}
    \def\ag{{#1}[5]}
%
    \def\lw{0.15mm}
%
    \coordinate (1) at (0,{(\dr+\dt)*(1-cos(\ag))+\dd*sin(\ag)});
    \coordinate (3) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)},{(\dr+\dt)*(1-cos(\ag))});
    \coordinate (5) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+(\dr+\dt)*sin(\ag)},0);
    \coordinate (7) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db-\dt-\dr},0);
    \coordinate (9) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db},{\dt+\dr});
    \coordinate (11) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db},{\dh-\dt-\dr});
    \coordinate (13) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db+\dr},{\dh-\dt});
    \coordinate (15) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt-\dr*sin(\ag)},{\dh-\dt});
    \coordinate (17) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt-\dr*cos(\ag)},{\dh-\dt-\dr*(1-cos(\ag))});
    \coordinate (19) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt},{\dh-\dt-\dr*(1-cos(\ag))-\dd*sin(\ag)});
%
    \draw [line width=\lw] (1) -- (3) (5) -- (7) (9) -- (11) (13) -- (15) (17) -- (19);
\end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
\centering
\test{16,6,0.3,0.8,2.91,60}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @Fractal, but they are already started from zero: `{#1}[0] ... {#1}[5]`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I need a new pair of glasses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pgfmath` commands for `pgfmath` things. Btw your figure is way too big.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dh{{#1}[0]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\db{{#1}[1]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dt{{#1}[2]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dr{{#1}[3]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dd{{#1}[4]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ag{{#1}[5]}
%
    \def\lw{0.15mm}
%
    \coordinate (1) at (0,{(\dr+\dt)*(1-cos(\ag))+\dd*sin(\ag)});
    \coordinate (3) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)},{(\dr+\dt)*(1-cos(\ag))});
    \coordinate (5) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+(\dr+\dt)*sin(\ag)},0);
    \coordinate (7) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db-\dt-\dr},0);
    \coordinate (9) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db},{\dt+\dr});
    \coordinate (11) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db},{\dh-\dt-\dr});
    \coordinate (13) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db+\dr},{\dh-\dt});
    \coordinate (15) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt-\dr*sin(\ag)},{\dh-\dt});
    \coordinate (17) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt-\dr*cos(\ag)},{\dh-\dt-\dr*(1-cos(\ag))});
    \coordinate (19) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt},{\dh-\dt-\dr*(1-cos(\ag))-\dd*sin(\ag)});
%
    \draw [line width=\lw] (1) -- (3) (5) -- (7) (9) -- (11) (13) -- (15) (17) -- (19);
\end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
\centering
\test{16,6,0.3,0.8,2.91,60}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### NOTES

- I think this is an XY problem. You might want to draw a figure based on some parameters. In that case, a macro is not the right way to go. You should use a `pic` instead.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{tikz}

  \tikzset{
    yourpicname/.pic={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dh{{#1}[0]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\db{{#1}[1]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dt{{#1}[2]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dr{{#1}[3]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dd{{#1}[4]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ag{{#1}[5]}
      \coordinate (1) at (0,{(\dr+\dt)*(1-cos(\ag))+\dd*sin(\ag)});
      \coordinate (3) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)},{(\dr+\dt)*(1-cos(\ag))});
      \coordinate (5) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+(\dr+\dt)*sin(\ag)},0);
      \coordinate (7) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db-\dt-\dr},0);
      \coordinate (9) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db},{\dt+\dr});
      \coordinate (11) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db},{\dh-\dt-\dr});
      \coordinate (13) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db+\dr},{\dh-\dt});
      \coordinate (15) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt-\dr*sin(\ag)},{\dh-\dt});
      \coordinate (17) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt-\dr*cos(\ag)},{\dh-\dt-\dr*(1-cos(\ag))});
      \coordinate (19) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt},{\dh-\dt-\dr*(1-cos(\ag))-\dd*sin(\ag)});
      \draw [pic actions] (1) -- (3) (5) -- (7) (9) -- (11) (13) -- (15) (17) -- (19);
    }
  }

  \begin{document}
  \centering
  \tikz\pic[line width=0.15mm,red]{yourpicname={16,6,0.3,0.8,2.91,60}};
  \end{document}
  ```
- If you want to stick with macros, I recommend this version, in which you can change `line width` and get rid of one macro.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{tikz}

  \newcommand{\test}[2][0.15mm]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  %
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dh{{#2}[0]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\db{{#2}[1]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dt{{#2}[2]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dr{{#2}[3]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dd{{#2}[4]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ag{{#2}[5]}
  %
      \coordinate (1) at (0,{(\dr+\dt)*(1-cos(\ag))+\dd*sin(\ag)});
      \coordinate (3) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)},{(\dr+\dt)*(1-cos(\ag))});
      \coordinate (5) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+(\dr+\dt)*sin(\ag)},0);
      \coordinate (7) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db-\dt-\dr},0);
      \coordinate (9) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db},{\dt+\dr});
      \coordinate (11) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db},{\dh-\dt-\dr});
      \coordinate (13) at ({\dd*cos(\ag)+\db+\dr},{\dh-\dt});
      \coordinate (15) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt-\dr*sin(\ag)},{\dh-\dt});
      \coordinate (17) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt-\dr*cos(\ag)},{\dh-\dt-\dr*(1-cos(\ag))});
      \coordinate (19) at ({2*(\dd*cos(\ag)+\db)-\dt},{\dh-\dt-\dr*(1-cos(\ag))-\dd*sin(\ag)});
  %
      \draw [line width=#1] (1) -- (3) (5) -- (7) (9) -- (11) (13) -- (15) (17) -- (19);
  \end{tikzpicture}
      }

  \begin{document}
  \centering
  \test{16,6,0.3,0.8,2.91,60}
  \test[0.3mm]{1,2,3,4,5,6}
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: `\pgfmathsetmacro` worked for me, is the problem risen from the size of the picture I am drawing? BTW, I want to put many of these drawings together to form kind of package to automate some of my drawings in LaTeX; so I want to go with macros...

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer (1) No, the problem is that you are not supposed to use `\def` there. (2) Glad to hear that you are writing a package. However there is no reason to avoid defining pics in packages, especially when they are more suitable than normal macros.

Comment: Thank you very much... I just have very little knowledge of LaTeX and have not previously written any macros... So, I am just thinking about a flow chart, search for it and do the code. That is why my choices may fall in bad options. But I really want to learn more on macros. I will search for that pics. And I should accept your answer, it is great.

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer Glad to help!

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer If you “*really* want to learn more on macros” and have some time, I'd suggest you read the TeXbook. LaTeX tutorials and even Lamport's book *LaTeX, a Document Preparation System,* are too superficial on programming matters, in my experience.

Comment: @frougon Yes I really want. I spend some time on LaTeX each day. I will read it. I am afraid my major is not computer engineering or computer science and consequently do not understand lots of the content.

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer The TeXbook requires one to read carefully because there are a lot of subtle points and exercises are often tough, but it doesn't really require a background in computer science. It won't have helped much for this question, because it has to do with how PGF & Ti*k*Z parse expressions, but it will help with many other things you've been discussing lately (`\def`, `\newdimen`... once you've read enough of the TeXbook, you can read the source code for `\newlength`, `\setlength` and [more difficult] `\newcommand` and better understand the relations between all  these).

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer Basically, learning TeX will provide you with good foundations which will make the documentation of `pgfkeys` reasonably understandable, which is necessary, IMHO, to be really comfortable with PGF & Ti*k*Z. It is like a building: you don't usually sleep in the foundations, but they are necessary to have something solid. :-) The same applies to the `expl3` docs: they are easy to read if you understand the underlying TeX concepts; otherwise, I think they must be rather difficult to grasp in many places.

Comment: @frougon wow, I got really excited about reading it. I will start it in very near future... let's call it a 2020 TeX target for me :-) Thank you very much for talking about it with me.